# how to exclude the folder from aws s3 sync command

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jenkins-cli

We have an aws s3 sync command that sync's the data from bitbucket to s3 via Jenkins execute shell. 
Below is the s3 bucket structure

```
cdn-accountname > qa > sitename > cdn > img
cdn-accountname > qa > sitename > cdn > css
cdn-accountname > qa > sitename > cdn > png
```

We use below command to sync the cdn content from bitbucket to s3

```
aws s3 sync cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename
```

I would like to exclude "/upload" and "/upload_qa" folders within cdn/ folder and sync it to s3. I tried below commands but none of them worked

```
aws s3 sync --exclude "cdn/upload" --exclude "cdn/upload_qa" cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename
aws s3 sync --exclude=cdn/upload --exclude=cdn/upload_qa cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename
aws s3 sync --exclude "*/upload/*" --exclude "*/upload_qa/*" cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename
aws s3 sync --exclude 'upload/*' --exclude 'upload_qa/*' cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename 
aws s3 sync cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename --exclude 'upload/*' --exclude 'upload_qa/*'
aws s3 sync cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename --exclude "cdn/upload" --exclude "cdn/upload_qa"
aws s3 sync cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename --exclude=cdn/upload --exclude=cdn/upload_qa
aws s3 sync cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename --exclude "*/upload/*" --exclude "*/upload_qa/*"
```

suggest the workable s3 sync command to sync the folder excluding sub-folder

Comment: Is there a particular error you're getting?

Comment: There will be no errors. When I run the sync command then both upload and upload_qa folders within cdn folder are getting synced to s3. But the expected output should be that they should be excluded from the sync and should not be copied to the s3 bucket.

Comment: The command `aws s3 sync cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename --exclude "upload/*" --exclude "upload_qa/*"` should work just fine. Are you sure `/upload` and `/upload_qa` are being synced every time? Maybe they got synced initially and remained there after adding the `--exclude` switch. Did you try to delete them from S3 before syncing?

Comment: Yes, Every time I running the sync command those files and synced to s3 and then I go back there and delete those files, and try again. But none of the above sync commands worked.

Comment: Try running: 
`aws s3 sync cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename --include "*" --exclude "upload/*" --exclude "upload_qa/*"`

Comment: still not working. Let me check directly with AWS support team.

Comment: For now, I am using aws rm command to remove both uploads and uploads_qa folders after the aws sync is done. 
That is: `aws s3 sync cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename/uploads
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename/uploads_qa` 
Let me know if someone could help on this

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll need to also use the `--include` flag in your command (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) for reference)

```
aws s3 sync --include "*" --exclude "upload/*" --exclude "upload_qa/*" cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname/qa/sitename
```

Be careful the order

> When there are multiple filters, the rule is the filters that appear
>   later in the command take precedence over filters that appear earlier
>   in the command

Tested this out and working fine

```
home [~]: aws s3 ls s3://abc-fe-testing1
                           PRE folder1/
                           PRE folder2/
                           PRE folder3/
                           PRE folder4/
home [~]: aws s3 ls s3://abc-fe-testing2
home [~]: aws s3 sync s3://abc-fe-testing1 s3://abc-fe-testing2 --exclude "folder1*" --exclude "folder2*"
copy: s3://abc-fe-testing1/folder4/file_from_folder4.txt to s3://abc-fe-testing2/folder4/file_from_folder4.txt
copy: s3://abc-fe-testing1/folder3/file_from_folder3.txt to s3://abc-fe-testing2/folder3/file_from_folder3.txt
home [~]: aws s3 ls s3://abc-fe-testing2
                           PRE folder3/
                           PRE folder4/
```

Comment: Still, it is not working. I even included the exclude folders in single quotes and also tried several orders but still, both the upload folders are synced to s3. I even gone through aws cli page and tried other options as well but none of them worked. Its there any other things I could try

Comment: Working okay for me.  I updated the answer to show how it worked for me

Comment: I have used below commands in the Jenkins execute shell section, but still, the excluded folders are synced to s3


`aws s3 sync cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname /qa/sitename --exclude "uploads*" --exclude "uploads_qa*"
aws s3 sync cdn/ s3://cdn-accountname /qa/sitename  --exclude "cdn/uploads*" --exclude "cdn/uploads_qa*"`


here cdn is a folder within my bitbucket repository and this folder has various directories among which I need to exclude "upload" and "upload_qa" directories while sync to s3